# add a row to a model

Tags: php, model, yii

I want to fill an empty model and save the model in a blob field for later use. My issue is i can not find how to add anouther row to the empty Model.

this works:

```
$test = LineItem::model();
$test->item_id = '2';
```

This does not work

```
$test->1->item_id = '3';
```

or

```
$test->item_id[1] = '3';
```

i have tried looking in the Yii documentation but i was unable to find an answer.

Thanks

**Clarification**
Im trying to create a false table using the model of a real table. I'm working on an invoicing system and i don't want to right the line items or invoice body information to the DB until it is "closed". Instead i want to fill the corresponding models that will then be serialized and stored in a BLOB field. Once the invoice is finished the data will be written to the table.

Comment: I'm not sure you're doing this the right way. Serialising a model row, inserting it into a BLOB in an in-memory database sounds like a lot of hassle - I think it would be better to write it to a real database row, but have an `is_closed` boolean column that you can set when the invoice becomes closed.

Comment: @halfer, Thanks for the suggestion. I'm actually doing this now but it is causing issue with no consecutive Invoice numbers. If the window gets closed or the invoice is not finished it sits open in the DB. I was hoping to avoid this. I also wanted to use the above mentioned scheme as a tracking and archive method for changes. Thinking about it over the weekend i may go back to my previous array scheme and forgo using the DB's models.

Comment: I think it is fine for it to 'sit open' in the db, for as long as the user doesn't explicitly close it. If your issue is that invoice numbers _should_ be consecutive and at present aren't, then I wonder if you are trying to use a primary key as a public invoice number? I think that may not be the best solution; primary and foreign keys are for referential integrity, not for human reference. Add another column (with a unique constraint if appropriate) for your sequential customer invoice number - and if appropriate to your ERD, have it nullable, so only real invoices ('closed'?) get one.

Comment: @halfer..  Thanks for the suggestion.. I was using the tables PK for the visible invoice number but i like the idea of have second column to hold the visible invoice number.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$test = new LineItem;
```

instead of

```
$test = LineItem::model();
```

for INSERT queries. And after setting properties

```
$test->save();
```

And so in every iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but not what im looking for.. I need to add a line to the model only and not save it to the DB. IE I want to create a in memory table using the model.

Comment: Oh, sorry. But I think these operations are in responsiblity of DataBase engine, not for ORM.